# Copying multiple folder file in same folder using puppet

Tags: puppet

I am trying to come up with a puppet module `sensu_client` that installs and configures sensu client in an instance.

The module directory structure is like this:

```
.
|-- examples
|-- files
|   |-- client-ssl
|   |-- custom_plugins
|   |   |-- common
|   |   `-- <env>
|   `-- default_plugins
|-- manifests
|-- spec
|   `-- classes
`-- templates
    `-- custom_plugins
        |-- common
        `-- <env>
```

Folders and their descriptions are something like this:

`files/default_plugins/`: default plugins from internet
`files/custom_plugins/common`: plugins that we write, irrespective of environment
`files/custom_plugins/<env>`: environment specific plugins that we write

and same idea for template directory.

If possible, I would like to copy all these plugins to same folder `/etc/sensu/plugins` in clients because in our other environments ( which we manage using ansible ), we have standardized the sensu plugin location to be `/etc/sensu/plugins` folder.

When I run the manifest that I have written, I get this error message:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Cannot alias File[copy common custom plugins] to ["/etc/sensu/plugins/"] at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/<env>/modules/sensu_client/manifests/config.pp:46; resource ["File", "/etc/sensu/plugins/"] already declared at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/<env>/modules/sensu_client/manifests/config.pp:46 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/<env>/modules/sensu_client/manifests/config.pp:46:3 on node <fqdn>
```

which is obvious now, because I have several file blocks where I am trying to copy files/templates to `/etc/sensu/plugins` directory.

Can you guys please point me to the recommended way for getting this done?

Another small thing related that I am trying to achieve but not getting done, is this. I want to generate `/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json` file which looks something like this

```
{
  "client": {
    "name": "<hostname>",
    "address": "<ip address>",
    "subscriptions": ["<hostname>", "all", "<env>", "<service>"]
  }
}
```

There are two environments where we run puppet, and the naming convention follows this pattern.

Environment 1: FQDN is `<env>-<service><index>.<domain-name1>.tld` and hostname is `<env>-<service><index>`
Environment 2: FQDN is `<service><index>.<domain-name2>.tld` and hostname is `<service><index>`

My template file for the same looks like this:

```
{
  "client": {
    "name": "<%= @hostname %>",
    "address": "<%= @ipaddress %>",
    "subscriptions": <%= @pr_subscription_array %>
  }
}
```

where I am getting pr_subscription_array in my manifest using this block:

```
$pr_service_name = regsubst("${facts[hostname]}", '^(.*?)-([a-zA-Z]*)[0-9]*', '\2')
$pr_subscription_array = [ "${facts[hostname]}", "all", "${facts['agent_specified_environment']}", "$pr_service_name" ]
```

This is generating the subscription like this: `"subscriptions": ["<hostname>", "all", "<env>", "<service><index>"]`

Some how service field is not coming properly. It comes with the index number. Any suggestions on how to get this done using puppet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you're going to the effort of writing your own module here and not using https://forge.puppet.com/sensu/sensu ?